# How to make a string which contains special characters?

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I have the below data which I want to make as String and I want to keep all spacial character as it is:

`, ref : "[REF]",  r: "[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]"});`

This what I tried but it is giving an error:

```
String data=", ref : "[REF]",  r: "[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]"});";
```

How can I make this data into string variable?

Comment: use \ for your double quotes "

Answer (score 3):

You can create as follows:

```
String data=", ref : \"[REF]\",  r: \"[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]\"});";
```